# Automatically replace RAISERROR with THROW in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am looking for an automated way of replacing the `RAISERROR` portion with new syntax `THROW` on 100's of stored procs that is currently being migrated from **SQL Server 2008 to 2012.**

Has anyone ran into a similar situation like this before? If so, how did you go about handling? I am really looking for an answer where I don't have to go through each stored proc and find the `RAISERROR` section and manually change it to use `THROW` instead.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add a comment/suggestions if you need more information. Down-voting seems a bit laziness and lack of knowledge/interest in the question.

Comment: `Throw` and `raiserror` do different things and it's not just a matter of syntax to replace them. E.g. after `raiserror` execution continues to the next statement if the procedure, while `throw` immediately takes you out to the closest error handler, or to the client if no error handlers found (actually even more complicated: `raiserror` acts like `throw` inside a `try` block, but acts in the old way when not). Also it is not straightforward to replace a `raiserror` that uses parameters (`%s`, `%d`) to generate the error string.

Comment: @GSerg  That seems like a pretty fair assessment on `raiserror` syntax. I am still interested to know if somebody has run into a situation they were working on migrating stored procs from `SQL Server 2008` to `SQL Server 2012` and dealt with converting the `raiserror` to `throw` in some kind of automated way.

Comment: Most likely you'll need to script out the procs, write some code to do the string replacements, then apply the procs.   I've never done it, but if it were my task, that is what i would have to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @Greg. How would you go about automating the process of doing such string replacement? Using Powershell maybe?

Comment: C# or Java, IMO.  Most likely something that uses regex.